# Increase the font size on homescreen tiles

Tags: settings, tiles

We can increase the size of fonts that appear within any app, by going to
`Settings > Ease of access > Text size`. Now how to increase the font size on the tiles of the home screen?

Answer (score 2):

there is no such feature available in windows phone 8.1 or Windows 10mobile.
Size in the tile is fixed. you cannot change it.